# Can a non-broken switch cause issues connecting to a server attached to it?

Tags: networking, router, raspberry-pi, webserver, switch

long time reader, first time poster here. I'm experiencing connectivity issues with a server. Here's the background story:

- I have a small Raspberry Pi 3 Model B acting as a server running a Nextcloud instance on Arch Linux.
- It's located at my home, behind a FritzBox 7530 router. IP addresses and DNS are dynamic.
- Everything has been running fine for much more than a year without issues.

One day I decided to put a small, cheap, unmanaged switch (TP-Link TL-SG105) in between the server and the router. Some other devices, like a desktop PC and a docking station for a laptop, are connected to the switch as well. The (weird?) problem is this:

- When all other devices (PC / Laptop) are switched off, I often fail to connect to the server. Happens ~every day, but not all the time.
- When any of the other devices is switched on, there have never been any connectivity issues
- When removing the switch from the setup the server is always reachable. I just verified this again over 2 weeks while being on vacation.

There are some more aspects worth mentioning. First of all, during times when the server is unreachable through the internet, I cannot ping it from e.g. my phone on the same network (Wlan), and I verified with tcpdump+wireshark that the ICMP (ping) packets do not arrive at the server. When the server is reachable through the internet, ping (on the local network) works fine. And secondly I just verified again that the server becomes reachable instantly when I switch on my desktop PC.

All in all I think it's safe to conclude that the problem as well as the observation that it goes away when switching on devices attached to the switch is reproducible.

So the question is: Is this due to the switch, and in which way? Or is it due to some network layout problem, or just me failing to understand something obvious? Should I get a "better" switch, and in which sense should it be better? I actually also tried using a NETGEAR GS305 switch, but exactly the same connectivity issue showed up. Could it be to the "Green Ethernet" functionality of these switches? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Output of ethtool on the server

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Very interesting question.  It doesnt look to me that the TP-Link TL-SG105 has "green ethernet", so that would make this seem unlikely - but I can't posit a better explanation.  Are you able to plug your Pi into a LAN port directly on the FritzBox rather then a switch and see if the problem goes away?  It sounds to me like it is an issue with the Pi, or maybe a driver issue.  What is the output of  "sudo lspci"  and "sudo lsusb" ?  Also, can you run "sudo ethtool DEVNAME" and provide the output.  (Maybe DEVNAME is eth0?)

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not a TL-SG105E? Which version of the TL-SG105 is it?

Comment: have you specified a link speed and duplex mode on the server, or is it on Arch's version of Auto-negotiated? it doesn't account for everything you have reported, but generally if you manually configure nic settings like those, you need to do so on both ends or you run the risk of unreliable connections. also how are you handling your naming? dns? what device handles dns resolution?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I can confirm that the label on the switch says "TL-SG105", not "...105E". Not sure if I can get more information about the version except the serial number. That version was advertised as featuring "green ethernet", but I didn't check more closely to be honest.
Plugging the Pi directly into the FritzBox is what I tried to describe above as the working setup; sorry for being unclear about this.
The FritzBox handles DNS resolution, and it does so quite reliably it seems. Haven't had issues with this yet.
And I added the ethtool output to the question.